# Racket Tests not running because "application not a procedure"

Tags: testing, racket

I keep getting an error saying: application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
  arguments...:
   8
My code is below. What is wrong with it I've tried for so long but can't find why I keep getting that error???

```
test 'you need more tests':
    let h = HashTable(10, SboxHash64())
    assert 'hello' not in h
    h['hello'] = 5
    assert h.len() == 1
    assert 'hello' in h
    assert h['hello'] == 5
    h['hellooo'] = 7
    assert h.len() == 2
    assert h['hello'] == 5
    assert h['hellooo'] == 7
    h.del('hello')
    assert h.len() == 1
    assert 'hello' not in h
    assert 'hellooo' in h
    h.del('hellooo')
    assert h.len() == 0
```

Comment: What language is this? It looks kindof like [`#lang dssl2`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/dssl2/index.html), is that right?

Comment: yes it is #lang dssl2, do you know whats wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Could the problem be with how are `HashTable` or `SboxHash64` is defined? Or one of the methods on them anyway?

Comment: (I'm not very familiar with `#lang dssl2`, so correct me if I'm wrong) From reading the dssl2 documentation, it looks like `a[b]` bracket-access syntax only works for vectors and strings. Does bracket-access work on HashTables?

Comment: You need a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Eg. I should be able to paste in that into DrRacket and get the same error when hitting RUN.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexKnauth is correct, the bracket-access syntax works for (built in) Vectors and strings.

@AlexKnauth scripsit:

> From reading the dssl2 documentation, it looks like `a[b]` bracket-access syntax only works for vectors and strings.

Comment: Turning a comment into an answer is appreciated. But please add more info; at least the info in the comment (which theoretically might get deleted). Ideally add more info, and explanation, according to [answer]. Consider taking the recommended [tour].